# Accessing data from service in other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was given below task in an interview, here the task is about getting a response from API using ajax call on button click and display it on a page.

I have a top component inside App.js, with two child components as MyButton.js and MyPage.js and the service code in MyAPI.js

Below are the file contents:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyAPI from './services/MyAPI';
import MyButton from './components/MyButton';
import MyPage from './components/MyPage';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {
      'apiResponse': ''
    };
  }

  handleButtonClick = () => {
    MyAPI.getAPIResponse().then((res) => {
        res => this.setState({ apiResponse })
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center><MyButton onClickButton={this.handleButtonClick}></MyButton></center>
        <MyPage apiResponse={this.props.apiResponse}></MyPage>
      </div>
    );
  }


}

export default App;
```

**MyButton.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const MyButton = (() => (
  <div className="button-container">
    <MyButton variant="extendedFab" color="primary"
      onClick={this.props.onClickButton}>
      Call API
    </MyButton>
  </div>
));


MyButton.propTypes = {
    onClickButton: PropTypes.func
}

export default MyButton;
```

**MyPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const MyPage = (() => (
  <Paper className="container">
      <List>
          <ListItem>
          <ListItemText>Name: {this.props.apiResponse.split(" ")[0]}</ListItemText>
      </ListItem>
      </List>
  </Paper>
));

MyPage.propTypes = {
  apiResponse: PropTypes.string
}

export default MyPage;
```

**MyAPI.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    getAPIResponse() {
        return axios.get("--url to get user name and age as json--").then(response => {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
};
```

Here the JSON data contains the name of a sample user just for demo purpose eg: `John Doe`. I need to display only `John` on my page as per the given task.

When I run this application I am getting errors at my `MyButton.js` and `MyPage.js` in logs.

In `MyButton.js` the error is at line `onClick={this.props.onClickButton}`, it says cannot access props on undefined. If I change it to `onClick={this.onClickButton}`, I got an error as, cannot access onClickButton on undefined. What is the correct way to do this here, please help.

Also same applies to `MyPage.js` at line `{this.props.apiResponse.split(" ")[0]`, also is it the right way to use the split method here to get the first name from `John Doe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **MyButtn** and **MyPage** both are functional components. To access the `props` you do not need to use `this`. props are taken as params in case of functional components.

**MyButton**

```
const MyButton = ((props) => (
  <div className="button-container">
    <MyButton variant="extendedFab" color="primary"
      onClick={props.onClickButton}>
      Call API
    </MyButton>
  </div>
));
```

**MyPage**

```
const MyPage = ((props) => (
  <Paper className="container">
      <List>
          <ListItem>
          <ListItemText>Name: {props.apiResponse.split(" ")[0]}</ListItemText>
      </ListItem>
      </List>
  </Paper>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

once the response success you have to store in the variable

```js
var a = "jhon doe";
var data = a.split(" ");
data[0];
```

you can do this in a parent component.